# Find equation of line such that area formed by line & positive coordinate axis is minimal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, vector-spaces

Find equation of line passing through $(20,12)$ such that the area of the triangle formed by the line and the positive axis is smallest possible.

Also: $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x}{b}=1$
where $a, b$ are x, y intercepts

So far, I have

$$A=\frac{1}{2}ab, \qquad line = (20,12)+\lambda(a,-b)$$

I need to find min area, so I need to differentiate $A$ but with respect to what? From what I have, I can't really find a way to express 1 term in terms of another. If I try to express 1 term in terms of 3 others from $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x}{b}=1$, it doesn't appear useful.

**UPDATE**

I think the picture will look like:

[image]

Comment: "Axis" is singular; the plural is "axes". Do you mean the triangle formed by the line, the nonnegative half $x$-axis, and the nonnegative half $y$-axis?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean, see update for a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is off the top of my head, so MMMV.)

Since the line passes through (20, 12),
$20/a + 12/b = 1$, or
$20/a = 1-12/b = (b-12)/b$,
or
$a = 20b/(b-12)$,
so $ab/2 = 20b^2/(b-12)$.

The derivative, ignoring the 20, is
$\frac{b^2 - 2b(b-12)}{(b-12)^2}$
which is zero when 
$b^2 = 2b(b-12)$ or $b = 2(b-12)$
or $b=24$.

$a$ then is $20\ 24/12$ or $40$,
and the area is 480.

As to why this lists differential equations and vector spaces, beats me.

Comment: I have +1'd the answer. But helping me decipher what MMMV is would be most welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I actually dont really understand the hint $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b}=1$. How do I get that equation?

Comment: MMMV = My Mileage May Vary (my punning takeoff on YMMV).